# Set Queue Path in Web.config

Tags: c#, web-config, msmq

I am using MSMQ in C#, how can i set **queuepath** in **web.config**?

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was really simple i found solution.

```
<add key="MSMQName" value=".\private$\WebSiteEmails"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an `appSetting` key with the path of your Queque ?

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="myquequepath" value="FormatName:DIRECT=OS:machinename\private$\MyQueue" />
  </appSettings>
```

Comment: I was using it like this: @".\private$\WebSiteEmails", i am using windows 7 OS. how it should look like?

Comment: That queque is for accessing a remote queque, if your one is local your key should be fine.